# PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions) hangs app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, parse-platform

Using the latest FB iOS SDKS and Parse, and ParseFacebookUtilsV4

```
 pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
 pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
 pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
 pod 'Parse'
 pod 'ParseUI'
 pod 'ParseCrashReporting'
 pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
```

My application hangs on launch. Here's my app delegate code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    configurePushNotifications(application)
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
        $0.applicationId = "myapp"
        $0.clientKey = "123123123"
        $0.server = "https://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/parse"
    }
    Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(configuration)


    if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    } else {
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions([NSObject:AnyObject]())
    }
```

The last call is causing the app the hang, specifically in the block:

```
- (PFUserAuthenticationController *)userAuthenticationController {
    __block PFUserAuthenticationController *controller = nil;
    dispatch_sync(_controllerAccessQueue, ^{
        if (!_userAuthenticationController) {
            _userAuthenticationController = [PFUserAuthenticationController controllerWithDataSource:self];
        }
        controller = _userAuthenticationController;
    });
    return controller;
}
```

Inside `PFCoreManager.m`

I don't believe I am doing anything unusual here, and have tried deleting and reinstalling the app. The same things happens in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same problem. From reading recent release notes, some work was done to automatically register objects that implement the PFSubclassing protocol.

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/pull/967

I found that removing any explicit registering cleaned up this problem which included removing lines like this from the classes:

```
override public class func initialize() {
    self.registerSubclass()
}
```

The multiple registering seemed to create a deadlock on the _controllerAccessQueue that the userAuthenticationController also happened to use...